python datetime.datetime respecting tzinfo but datetime.time is not
In python 3.9:
datetime.datetime respects tzinfo but datetime.time does not appear to.
import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

dta = datetime.datetime.now(tz=ZoneInfo("America/Los_Angeles"))
dtp = datetime.datetime.now(tz=ZoneInfo("Europe/Paris"))

da10 = datetime.time(10, 0, tzinfo=ZoneInfo("America/Los_Angeles"))
dp10 = datetime.time(10, 0, tzinfo=ZoneInfo("Europe/Paris"))

# datetime.datetime correctly reports tzname and correctly reports 
# different time zone aware datetime.datetimes as unequal

>>> dta.tzname()
'PDT'
>>> dtp.tzname()
'CEST'
>>> dta == dtp
False

# datetime.time does not report tzname and incorrectly reports
# different time zone aware datetime.time as equal

>>> da10.tzname()
>>> dp10.tzname()
>>> da10 == dp10
True

datetime.datetime correctly reports tzname and correctly reports
different time zone aware datetime.datetimes as unequal
datetime.time does not report tzname and incorrectly reports
different time zone aware datetime.time as equal

dta and dtp are probably different times (by microseconds) since you used two different "now" calls.  I get True for dta==dtp when calling now once and converting to two different time zones from the result.

da10.utcoffset() and dp10.utcoffset() are both None.

Unlike datetime.datetime, the datetime.time object is not fully time-zone aware. It only stores a tzinfo attribute and it is not used in comparisons or in other methods like tzname().
datetime.time - is just a time-of-day object, and while it allows setting tzinfo, the timezone is merely stored but not used for operations like comparison.

That's not what the documentation says:
time objects support comparison of time to time, where a is considered less than b when a precedes b in time.
If both comparands are aware, and have the same tzinfo attribute, the common tzinfo attribute is ignored and the base times are compared. If both comparands are aware and have different tzinfo attributes, the comparands are first adjusted by subtracting their UTC offsets (obtained from self.utcoffset()).

@NmhorKmhor How would it know what utcoffset to use with a time and no date?  The offset varies depending on the date for DST.

@MarkTolonen, please see my comment in the next response.

Note that OP's dta and dtp are different times since two different .now() calls are made.  Below returns True when the same .now() is used and converted to different time zones.  They are the same time.
Times with time zones that have DST drop the time zone and compare as naive since a date is needed to determine the correct UTC offset to use.  But use a time zone that doesn't have DST where .utcoffset() is fixed instead of based on a date and it works:
import datetime as dt
import zoneinfo as zi

now = dt.datetime.now(tz=dt.UTC)  # Grab one aware time.

# Convert to two different time zones.
dta = now.astimezone(zi.ZoneInfo('America/Los_Angeles'))
dtp = now.astimezone(zi.ZoneInfo('Europe/Paris'))
print(f'{dta = !s}')
print(f'{dtp = !s}')
print(f'{dta == dtp = }')

# Compares false if using time zones without DST.
# Also .tzname() is not None and .utcoffset() has an offset
# instead of None due to a fixed offset that doesn't need a date reference.
#
# Note: This depends on the implementation of particular zones.  UTC and MST
# have a fixed utcoffset() that doesn't require a date; while
# US/Arizona, which doesn't have DST, implements utcoffset(dt) and
# returns None if the date is not provided.
#
da10 = dt.time(10, 0, tzinfo=zi.ZoneInfo('MST'))
dp10 = dt.time(10, 0, tzinfo=zi.ZoneInfo('UTC'))
print(f'{da10.tzname() = }, {da10.utcoffset() = !s}')
print(f'{dp10.tzname() = }, {dp10.utcoffset() = !s}')
print(f'{da10 == dp10 = }')
print()

# Compares True if using time zones with DST.
# Without a date, tzname and utcoffset are unknown (None).
da10 = dt.time(10, 0, tzinfo=zi.ZoneInfo('America/Los_Angeles'))
dp10 = dt.time(10, 0, tzinfo=zi.ZoneInfo('Europe/Paris'))
print(f'{da10.tzname() = }, {da10.utcoffset() = !s}')
print(f'{dp10.tzname() = }, {dp10.utcoffset() = !s}')
print(f'{da10 == dp10 = }')

Output:
dta = 2024-09-26 13:31:24.349530-07:00
dtp = 2024-09-26 22:31:24.349530+02:00
dta == dtp = True
da10.tzname() = 'MST', da10.utcoffset() = -1 day, 17:00:00
dp10.tzname() = 'UTC', dp10.utcoffset() = 0:00:00
da10 == dp10 = False

da10.tzname() = None, da10.utcoffset() = None
dp10.tzname() = None, dp10.utcoffset() = None
da10 == dp10 = True


Thanks for that information.  Based on a few samples, it seems most zones return None for utcoffset() even if they do not observe DST, e.g. "US/Hawaii" and "US/Arizona".  IMO, the documentation is misleading.  It should say that aware time comparands will only subtract the UTC offset if a UTC offset is available without a date and very few zones implement this.  In almost all cases time comparisons will be naive.
